# Convert string to guid in linq join query : conditional statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have linq query as below

```
using (RMPortalEntities _RMPortalEntities = new RMPortalEntities()) {

                var _RSVP_ButtonLocations = _RMPortalEntities
                                            .tbl_RSVP_ButtonLocation
                                            .Join(_RMPortalEntities.tbl_RSVP_Setting,
                                                            _RSVP_ButtonLocation => Guid.Parse(_RSVP_ButtonLocation.ID),
                                                            _RSVP_Setting => _RSVP_Setting.RSVP_Button_Location_ID,
                                                            (_RSVP_ButtonLocation, _RSVP_Setting) => new { _RSVP_ButtonLocation, _RSVP_Setting })
                                            .Join(_RMPortalEntities.tbl_Event,
                                                            _RSVP_ButtonLocation_RSVP_Setting => _RSVP_ButtonLocation_RSVP_Setting._RSVP_Setting.EventID,
                                                            _Event => _Event.ID,
                                                            (_RSVP_ButtonLocation_RSVP_Setting, _Event) => new { _RSVP_ButtonLocation_RSVP_Setting, _Event })
                                            .Where(x => x._Event.Active == true
                                                        && x._Event.ID == _EventID)
                                            .Select(x => new
                                            {

                                                RSVP_ButtonLocations = x._RSVP_ButtonLocation_RSVP_Setting._RSVP_ButtonLocation.RSVP_ButtonLocation

                                            });

                return _RSVP_ButtonLocations.FirstOrDefault().RSVP_ButtonLocations;
            }
```

But problem is linq query does not allow me to convert string to Guid value.
Could anyone give me suggestion please?

Comment: how about "new Guid(_RSVP_ButtonLocation.ID)" instead of "Guid.Parse(_RSVP_ButtonLocation.ID)" ?

Comment: @CjCoax, I update as you suggested, I get this message "System.NotSupportedException: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.
 "

Comment: @Frank, why do the data types used to join vary? Probably it would be better to have `Guid` in both tables?...If not, probably you could try to do the join vice versa: convert `Guid` to string, so join on string values...

Comment: Yes, @KonstantinVasilcov, Finally my solution is also making Guid data type for both of my tables keys.

Answer (score 0):

Building on CjCoax comment you can store an instance of GUID and then use it later in the query:

```
using (RMPortalEntities _RMPortalEntities = new RMPortalEntities()) {
            var GUID = new Guid(_RMPortalEntities.tbl_RSVP_ButtonLocation.ID);
            var _RSVP_ButtonLocations = _RMPortalEntities
                                        .tbl_RSVP_ButtonLocation
                                        .Join(_RMPortalEntities.tbl_RSVP_Setting,
                                                        _RSVP_ButtonLocation => GUID,
                                                        _RSVP_Setting => _RSVP_Setting.RSVP_Button_Location_ID,
                                                        (_RSVP_ButtonLocation, _RSVP_Setting) => new { _RSVP_ButtonLocation, _RSVP_Setting })
                                        .Join(_RMPortalEntities.tbl_Event,
                                                        _RSVP_ButtonLocation_RSVP_Setting => _RSVP_ButtonLocation_RSVP_Setting._RSVP_Setting.EventID,
                                                        _Event => _Event.ID,
                                                        (_RSVP_ButtonLocation_RSVP_Setting, _Event) => new { _RSVP_ButtonLocation_RSVP_Setting, _Event })
                                        .Where(x => x._Event.Active == true
                                                    && x._Event.ID == _EventID)
                                        .Select(x => new
                                        {

                                            RSVP_ButtonLocations = x._RSVP_ButtonLocation_RSVP_Setting._RSVP_ButtonLocation.RSVP_ButtonLocation

                                        });

            return _RSVP_ButtonLocations.FirstOrDefault().RSVP_ButtonLocations;
        }
```

Comment: ` var GUID = new Guid(_RSVP_ButtonLocation.ID);` How could i use that statement since `_RSVP_ButtonLocation` declaration do not come yet.

Comment: I appreciate your help @Sidharth Mudgal